How to compile RedisSearch Module from source
I have installed redis on my local machine (MacBook Pro Apple M1 Pro). I would like to build and load/install RediSearch module for a quick check. I am not using docker image, but would like to build it form source or optionally if the module binaries (redisearch.so) are already available for download.
I have downloaded source from github. I am trying to build the module from source .
Here are the steps followed:

Download source from https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch

Extract the zip file RediSearch-master.zip in Downloads directory

Use make command on the terminal
$ pwd
/Users/Downloads/RediSearch-master
$ make
Makefile:11: deps/readies/mk/main: No such file or directory
Makefile:250: /defs: No such file or directory
Makefile:288: /rules: No such file or directory
make: /bin/platform: Command not found
./sbin/pack.sh: line 7: /Users/Downloads/RediSearch-master/deps/readies/shibumi/defs: No such file or directory
./sbin/pack.sh: line 59: /Users/Downloads/RediSearch-master/deps/readies/bin/platform: No such file or directory
./sbin/pack.sh: line 63: /Users/Downloads/RediSearch-master/deps/readies/bin/platform: No such file or directory
./sbin/pack.sh: line 66: /Users/Downloads/RediSearch-master/deps/readies/bin/platform: No such file or directory
/Users/Downloads/RediSearch-master/sbin/getver: line 7: /Users/Downloads/RediSearch-master/deps/readies/shibumi/defs: No such file or directory
/Users/Downloads/RediSearch-master/sbin/getver: line 7: /Users/Downloads/RediSearch-master/deps/readies/shibumi/defs: No such file or directory
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
make: *** No rule to make target `/rules'.  Stop.


What am I missing? Or is it not supported on mac? I failed to find insturctions/documentation which shows how to build the module from source.
Thanks,
JE

RediSearch has some submodules it needs in order to by built. The zip file probably not including them.
You can try running make fetch that will attempt to fetch the submodules.
If it doesn’t work, I would guess it because of the way you downloaded the source code. I would suggest deleting what you’ve downloaded and clone the repository with git clone —-recursive https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch.git. The recursive flag will make sure to fetch all the required submodules

--recursive worked for me
